# Android MediaPlayer Error Feedback

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am using `MediaPlayer` in my code to play video.

This is the code :

```
mp.setDataSource(source);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
mp.prepareAsync();
```

In some cases the video is not playing(and if i call `mp.getDuration();` i get fail) and instead of getting `OnError` feedback i am getting `OnCompletion` feedback, and i can't know if any problem occurs.

And some times i get `OnError` function called.

Any idea how i can check if the mediaplayer was fail in the `OnCompletion` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Docs, 
`onErrorListener` returns:

> True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause the OnCompletionListener to be called.

So your `onCompletion` is being called when `onError` returns false.

Your implementation of `onErrorListener` should return true to avoid `onCompletion` to be called.

Comment: The problem is that `onCompletion` called before `onErrorListener`